# If padding is inside, why will the div be wider with padding?

Tags: html, css, padding

I have this div on the CSS:

```
#bodycontent {
    max-width:980px;
    margin:auto; 
}

#navleft {
    width:18%;   
    border:0px;
    float:left;
}

#rightcontent {
    max-width:80%;
    border:0px;
    float:right;
}
```

and on the HTML:

```
<div id="bodycontent">
    <div id="navleft">
        some stuff
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontent">
        some stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. If I set the divs 20% and 80% I'll have the divs displayed not side by side but one above and one below
2. I'd like to have 25px of padding-left on the rightcontent div but, again if I set the padding, the div goes below the other.

Why? The padding is not inside?

Comment: This is because of the box model. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `width` property is [defined (in CSS 2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-dimensions) as *the width of the content*, not the space between the borders. Padding goes inside the borders, not inside the width.

In CSS 3, you can change this with the [`box-sizing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) but this has [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing).

Comment: What would you suggest to create space between the div's? Reduce the % of the width and add some padding? Is this not dangerous if the browser or the screen resolution changes?

Comment: To support CSS 2 browsers, I'd use gives with no margin/padding to set the columns, and then put another div inside each of them which has the desired padding.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are facing is because of the box model.  The width you declare is the width of the content and not the true width of the element.

To learn more about the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

To change this so that the border and padding are all part of the elements width you can use `border-box`

```
#your-element { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: 
     border-box; box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read about the [css box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Your content is the inner-most box, and it will have the `width` you specify.  Padding, border, and margin are all added to this width.  Padding will be inside the border, but not inside the content width.